# graphicon over home image doesnt show text box on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

Similar to what Patagonia (http://www.patagonia.com/) has done, where they have a camera icon on top of the home page image, when you hover over the icon a text box pops up. I've tried to play with Patagonia's html and css, but I messed up somewhere. Now I'm not seeing either the icon or the text box. I did see one or the other before, but they were showing up below the home page image, and the hover did nothing. 
my css:

```
`
    photo-caption-icon, .photo-icon {
        z-index: 100;
        font-size: 200%;
        color: #bddadb;
    }

    .home-img .photo-caption {
        bottom: 40px;
    }

     .glyphicon, .photo-caption-icon, .photo-icon {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    .photo-caption-text {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: -7px;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px 30px 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.65);
        transition: .5s ease;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
         visibility: hidden;
        transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
    }

    .home-img__wrap {
          position: relative;
          height: 200px;
          width: 257px;
     }


    .img__wrap:hover .img__description {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
    }

    .photo-caption {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 50px;
        color: black;
    }

    .image-slider li {
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
`

my html:
`
    <div class="home-img"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-288 size-full"     src="https://radicalurge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Brigid-with-jewlery-1.jpg" alt="model wearing Radical Urge logo t-shirt" width="100%" />


    <div class="photo-caption photo-credits" style="display:block"> 
    <span class="photo-caption-icon" style="display:block;"> </span>

    <span class="photo-caption-text" >
Brigidlynn Cappelletti  /  Metalsmith</span>
    </div></div>
`
```

How do I get an icon to stay above the home page image, then how do I get the hover to show a text box over that icon?

Comment: new code <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" </span><span class="hoverinfo">Brigidlynn Cappelletti / Metalsmith</span></div>  and .glyphicon glyphicon-camera,  {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;    display: inline-block; font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    z-index: 100;  font-size: 200%; color: #bddadb;}
.hoverinfo {
   position: relative;  bottom: 0;
    right: -7px;  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 28px; color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;}.hoverinfo p {
  display: none;
  color: #000;}
.hoverinfo:hover p {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;}

Comment: I see the camera icon on Firefox, not chrome or Safari, and hover does not work, the text is always visible.  How do I fix this? https://radicalurge.com